# jQuery UI returning "undefined" for Timepicker add-on in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am attempting to utilize Trent Richardson's [TimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples) jQuery UI plugin to add a time picking widget to a Wordpress plugin. jQuery and jQuery UI are both enqueued as they should be and are working fine (the Datepicker/Slider requirements for TimePicker have both been verified to be included and working as well as the TimePicker script is loading fine).

However, Firebug is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: $.ui is undefined
```

The line in question is this:

```
$.ui.timepicker = $.ui.timepicker || {};
```

I understand that it's occurring because for some reason this script isn't finding $.ui (which I assume is a standard notation for referring to jQuery UI?) I also tried simply pre-defining the $.ui at the top and I got rid of that undefined error, but then it threw another for

```
$.datepicker
```

That is further on down in the code on line 973. There doesn't seem to be a lot of sense in explicitly defining $.ui and $.datepicker in the top of the script when they should be valid references to the jQuery objects... I'm just not sure how to fix what appears to be a broken link.

Comment: Do you have a live version we can see? Without seeing the rest of your page this is hard to diagnose.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's in my local dev version. I found another solution though which you can find in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding another [TimePicker](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker) plugin that worked right "out of the box" so to speak. Literally just changed the reference from the old jquery.timepicker.js to the new jquery.ui.timepicker.js and everything is working beautifully.

My general intuition/feeling on the "old" script is that it might be using either an outdated or advanced [api calling method](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/03/api-redesigns-the-past-present-and-future/) that is causing problems with jQuery's/UI's version.